# Script returns wanted strings, but with '\n' put after it

Tags: python, string, function, append, break

I have written this piece of code for a script that should check whether a word contains all vowels (so, e, u, i, o, a), case-insensitive:

```
def words_all_vowels(filename):
    """Returns a list of all words that contain all vowels, as found in the file with the given name."""
    result = []
    
    e = False
    a = False
    i = False
    o = False
    u = False
    
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            for r in range(len(line.lower())-1):
                if line.lower()[r:(r+1)] == "e":
                    e = True
                if line.lower()[r:(r+1)] == "a":
                    a = True
                if line.lower()[r:(r+1)] == "i":
                    i = True
                if line.lower()[r:(r+1)] == "o":
                    o = True
                if line.lower()[r:(r+1)] == "u":
                    u = True
            if e == True and a == True and i == True and o == True and u == True:
                print(line)
                result.append(line)
            
            #resetting for next word
            e == False
            a == False
            i == False
            o == False
            u == False
            
    return result
    
    pass  # TODO
```

Strange thing is that the script returns not only the string that is encaptured in my line variable, but with \n after it as well. This is the return for an arbitrary list of potential words with all vowels:

```
['Aboideaus\n',
 'seagull\n',
 'multidirectional\n',
 'lifeguard\n',
 'complaint\n',
 'overqualified\n']
```

This is not correct, as it also contains words that do not contain all vowels, but I will fix that later. All I'd like to know is where this '\n' is coming from. It looks like a break that somehow gets included in the string. The original document containing these words has the words separated by line so perhaps that is where it is coming from. I had this in another script as well so something must be wrong with the way I read these lines.

Comment: Use ``result.append(line.strip())`` to remove new line char.

Comment: this is inefficient. Try: `for line in f: if all(vowel in line.lower() for vowel in "aeiou"):` and `.strip()` the \n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `line.strip()` to remove the newline char when appending the result.

```py
def words_all_vowels(filename):
    """Returns a list of all words that contain all vowels, as found in the file with the given name."""
    result = []
    
    e = False
    a = False
    i = False
    o = False
    u = False
    
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            for r in range(len(line.lower())-1):
                if line.lower()[r:(r+1)] == "e":
                    e = True
                if line.lower()[r:(r+1)] == "a":
                    a = True
                if line.lower()[r:(r+1)] == "i":
                    i = True
                if line.lower()[r:(r+1)] == "o":
                    o = True
                if line.lower()[r:(r+1)] == "u":
                    u = True
            if e == True and a == True and i == True and o == True and u == True:
                print(line)
                result.append(line.strip()) # add strip
            
            #resetting for next word
            e == False
            a == False
            i == False
            o == False
            u == False
            
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is line have default \n in the end to go to the new line as your are reading from file
you can use `line.strip()`
or you can use `line.replace('\n','')`